# What is COSName.B?

Tags: pdfbox

Occasionally, we will get some PDF files which we split into pages and the resulting pages will be entirely too large. Upon inspecting the pages, each one has a COSName.B array which is "huge"

[image]

I've looked around but I cannot seem to get a definition of what this type of COS element. Removing the element before copying the page fixes my file size problem and the results look ok (to my eyes) but I'm fearful because I'm not sure what I'm removing.

Anyone know where I can find out more about this mystery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copied from the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):)

> An array that shall contain indirect references to all article beads
>   appearing on the page. The beads shall be listed in the array in
>   natural reading order.

You can make these visible with the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example in the source code download, or with the trunk snapshot PDFDebugger (but not the 2.0 PDFDebugger version). You can download it here:
https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-debugger/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Whether to delete this or not depends on what you want to do with the result PDF. If you want to do text extraction (or allow your clients to do it), then it shouldn't be deleted.

[image: PDFBox test file with beads]

Comment: Thanks for the reference Tilman. I guess I need to figure out why PDPage.importPage is producing such a large copy. With the beads, each page is around 38MB. Without the beads, they are 400-500k. I'll dig deeper.